# How can I resolve the 'Fatal error: Call to a member function is_on_sale() on a non-object' issue?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a WordPress Theme, with WooCommerce functionality.  However, I am having problems in generating the Basket page.  When on said page, I receive the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function is_on_sale() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/sale-flash.php
>   on line 26

**Line 26 Entry:**

```
<?php if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) : ?>

    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', '<span class="onsale">' . __( 'Sale!', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>', $post, $product ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

**Troubleshooting:**

- I have checked the Basket Page and the `[woocommerce_cart]` shortcode has been correctly entered.
- The 'Basket' page has been placed in the correct field within the WooCommerce settings.
- I have flushed the permalinks settings but this does not seem to have changed anything.
- Both WordPress and WooCommerce are all up to date.

**Side Note:**

I have placed `sale-flash.php` within `/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/theme_name/templates` folder and thought this may had been a factor.  Consequently, I deleted the file in this location but had no bearing on the outcome.  I still see the error message.

Comment: What makes you think `$product` is set at the point of your code?

Comment: non-object means it failed; use error reporting, check if something is set/not empty and run a `var_dump();`

Comment: @Adam Williams:  I am not entirely sure what you mean by this.  If you are referring to the code, I only referred to the error message and pasted the highlighted code.  @Fred -ii-:  Could you point me in the direction of how I can correctly run `var_dump();`  I tried referring to http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php but couldn't work out how to apply toe examples to my issue.

Comment: @Craig Apologies if I wasn't clear. I was asking you why you thought that `$product` would be set/available at your point in the code. @AltzeM has mentioned as much in their answer - point is, `$product` probably isn't set and you'll need to read up on WooCommerce to figure out how to properly get the product

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php
$product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID());
if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) : ?>

    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', '<span class="onsale">' . __( 'Sale!', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>', $post, $product ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Should be the `Accepted answer`

Answer (score 0):

$product must be an object. 
Did u instantied it by setting that `$product = new Product;` ?

Lets say u have class Product with function is_on_sale()

```
class Product {

    private $on_sale = x;

    public function is_on_sale() {

        return $this->on_sale;

    }

}
```

Your code should look like this

```
$product = new Product;


if($product->is_on_sale())
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that problem but at another place. If your page containt loop try add this code to your theme template....

```html
while( $product_query -> have_posts() ) : $product_query -> the_post(); 
    global $product, $post; //the code you need
    if ($product->id)       //the code you need
        {
        //loop product
        }
endwhile;
```

hope that helped